# Checking that ALL rows have met a certain criteria in a dataframe using iLoc

Tags: python, dataframe, rows

I need to make sure that ALL the rows have met a certain criteria not just some of them..

I have this code which returns TRUE when some of the rows meet the criteria..

Any idea how to only return TRUE when all the rows meet the criteria??

Thanks

```
  if position == -1:

if ((df.iloc[-rows]['ABC']) < level ):

  return True
else:
  return False

  elif position == 1:

if ((df.iloc[-rows]['ABC']) > level ):

  return True
else:
  return False
```

position, level and rows are parameters from a function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `.iloc[-rows]` part and use `.all()`

```
if position == -1:
  return (df["ABC"] < level).all()
elif position == 1:
  return (df["ABC"] > level).all()
```

Comment: Brilliant and thanks! So much more efficient and neat as well... Makes sense and I've learnt something!!! :-) Thanks again!

Comment: @ZakPinter No worries! Whenever you see `return True else False`, you can just return the conditional of the if statement. (Or if its `return False else True`, return `not conditional`)

Comment: I'll remember that for next time! :-)